# Weighted Average of PyTorch Tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor, weighted-average

I have two Pytorch tensors of the form [y11, y12] and [y21, y22]. How do I get the weighted mean of the two tensors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can add two tensors using `torch.add` and then get the mean of output tensor using `torch.mean`
assuming weight as 0.6 for tensor1 and 0.4 for tensor2
example:

```
tensor1 = [y11, y12] * 0.6 # multiplying with weight
tensor2 = [y21, y22] * 0.4 # multiplying with weight
pt_addition_result_ex = tensor1.add(tensor2) # addition of two tensors

torch.mean(pt_addition_result_ex) # mean of output tensors
```